# Where can I find the supporting jar files for "bms-samples-android-bluelist" Sample applications provided by Bluemix?

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Where can I find the SDKs (supporting .jar files) for the "bms-samples-android-bluelist" Sample applications provided by Bluemix? While searching for this I got the below thread. The page is not redirecting to the right page:

URL-> https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/mobilefirst/gettingstarted/android_existingproject.html#gettingstarted

Note: I'm using in Eclipse

Comment: I highly recommend moving away from Eclipse to use Android Studio and their Gradle build system. If that is not possible you should try the Gradle Plugin for Eclipse. By taking advantage of Gradle, you will not need to worry about locating or updating your dependencies with .jars, it can all be managed and pulled in at runtime from a single build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

For that document try changing the "Docs customized for type" field in the top right from Java to Android. This is a known issue and will hopefully be sorted out shortly, but the Android version of the doc has working links.

For the SDKs themselves please take a look at the Bluemix Mobile Services github as they are all hosted there. [Here's a link to the Bluemix Service Android Core SDK to get started.](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-android-core)

Hope this helps